# Send keystrokes at regular intervals using python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and would like some help creating a program that can, every 5 minutes or so, press ctrl+s, since this is a shortcut in many programs to save. I'm writing this to help my mom so I'm not worried too much about how long it takes. Thanks!

Comment: I would strongly suggest against such program. Since it is not required that Ctrl+S does that, you can create horrible scenarios. For some programs, Ctrl+S means *freezing* the application (*s* of *s*uspend).

Comment: take a look at pynput i think this would be rather easy with that

Comment: Thank you @JoranBeasley ! I'll look into that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not worried about about that since she (my mother) would only run this when she wanted it to save routinely. She only uses her computer for Excel 2003 and Word 2003 and both of those use Ctrl+S to save.

Comment: Office has an adjustable autosave frequency.  You can simply change it to 5 minutes and be done w/it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, python has no such feature. However on windows you can use vbscript and a batch file to do the same thing as in vbscript you can do:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "+s"
```

and in batch if you save the vbscript file as save.vbs :

```
:start
pushd %~dp0
cscript save.vbs
timout 300
goto start
```

When you want to finish you can quit it from your task manager.